# I'm trying to do a natural to binary number converter

Tags: java, binary

I am a 16 year old who is trying to learn to program in Java. I set out to create this code, but I don't know if it is quite right. Why are you asking me to turn "natural" into a static? Please make any comments you can think of about the code, I try to improve my programming skills, so any comments from someone who knows a little more than I do is helpful. Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prueba {

    static int natural;

    public Prueba () {
        natural = 1;
    }

    public int Binario(int natural) {
        int i = 1, bin = 0;
        while(natural>0) {
            if (natural % 2 == 0)
                natural = natural / 2;
            else {
                natural = (natural-1)/2;
                bin = bin + i;
            }
            i = i*10;
        }
        return bin;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Prueba a = new Prueba();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Natural to binary number converter. Press 0 to stop the program");
        while (natural != 0) {
            natural = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println(a.Binario(natural));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The main issue is that you are converting to a 32 bit integer. When you are trying to convert to binary, create a string *a textual representation of a base 2 number*. The way to do that is to use `StringBuilder`. Another thing is that you actually don't have a specific question. Working code can be posted to https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Be prepared for **a lot** of helpful comments there :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this was posted to stackoverflow instead of code review - there is no specific question.

Comment: The **natural** variable needs to be static if it is going to be used within a static method (like the **main()** method). Since the **Binario()** method is contained within the class **Prueba** you do not need to create an instance of **Prueba** to utilize that method: `System.out.println(Binario(natural));`. Method names should start with a lower letter case letter.

Comment: @MaartenBodwes This would be off-topic on CR because OP isn't sure if it works correctly. Also, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *needs focus*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353)

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ It works correctly. There isn't too much that can go wrong really, other than overflow of course. And the fact that it doesn't contain a question makes it off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a binary string you can do it this way. But there are a couple of things to watch out for (covered in the comments).

Also, when you say `natural` number to binary I am not sure if you mean just positive numbers or decimal numbers.  This method will handle both.  But negative decimal numbers will not have a negative sign in binary.  They will be shown in what is known as [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) form.  Something that you should become familiar with as you continue to learn programming.

```
public static String toBinary(int v) {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

     // since you want to handle negative numbers it's important
     // to check for not equal to 0.

     while(v != 0) {
         // insert the bit at index 0 of stringBuilder.
         // The & just masks off the low order bit and ignores
         // the others.  The result is the same as "v % 2".  But
         // I prefer bit manipulation when possible
         sb.insert(0,v&1);

         // this shifts all 32 bits right one bit and inserts a 0
         // on the left.
         v>>>=1;
     }
     return sb.toString();
}
```

Check the link for more on [Bit Masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing))